# Azure Function app source control with terraform

Tags: azure, github, azure-functions, terraform

I would like to deploy a Function App that has source control from github with terraform. I use the resource [azurerm_function_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app) that has an argument [source_control](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#source_control) but I am facing this issue :

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 137, in resource "azurerm_function_app" "example":
 137:   source_control = {

An argument named "source_control" is not expected here. Did you mean to
define a block of type "source_control"?
```

I am using that code :

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.54"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "example"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      kind                = "FunctionApp"
    
      sku {
        tier = "Standard"
        size = "S1"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
      name                       = "example_func"
      location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
      storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    
      source_control = {
        repo_url  = "https://github.com/myrepo"
        branch    = "master"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#source_control), `source_control` is a block which means is defined without the `=` sign:

```
source_control {

}
```

Instead of:

```
source_control = {

}
```

With the `=` sign is an argument, not a block.

Comment: Arh I can't believe I fell for such an easy trap. Thanks a lot of the help !